# Using both whitespaces and quotes as separator for awk

Tags: awk, logs

When doing

```
grep index.html /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log | awk '{print $1 $13}'
```

we have a whitespace delimiter by default.

**How to have both `"` and   as delimiters:**

```
www.example.com:443 1.2.3.4 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:07:35 +0100] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 8317 "https://www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
```

**such as we can get both the IP and the user-agent with `awk`?**

Using `awk -F'["]'` didn't seem to work.

The expected parsing should be:

```
www.example.com:443
1.2.3.4
-
-
[01/Feb/2021:15:07:35 +0100]
"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 
200 
8317 
"https://www.example.com/" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to treat whitespaces and quotes as separators? or do you want to treat sequences of non-whitespace characters and (possibly whitespace-containing) sequences of characters between quotes *as fields*? Please include your expected output to clarify.

Comment: Using space as a separator would give you each word of the user-agent part as a distinct awk field, which probably makes it even more useless than it usually is. But if you can ignore it, the parts before it probably have a fixed amount if whitespace-separated words because the URLs and paths should be URL-encoded (I think).

Comment: Otherwise, for mixed separator input like that, I'd just use Perl, a regex and capture groups, e.g. `(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+"([^"])*" ...`

Comment: @ilkkachu I edited to add the expected parsing.

Comment: @steeldriver I added the expected parsing in the question.

Comment: You will never get that parsing by just playing with the field separators. You have a space in `[01/Feb/2021:15:07:35 +0100]` and you have quotes both in the beginning and the end of your "fields".

Comment: with GNU awk you could possibly do it using FPAT to define a regex for the fields rather than the FS in between ex. `FPAT='"[^"]*"|\\[[^]]*\\]|[^[:blank:]]+'`

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the space in your character class:

```
echo 'word1 word2"word2 word4"word5' | 
    awk -F '[ "]'  '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { print $i } }'
```

Comment: I think all awks should treat `FS` as a regex (if it's longer than a single character), the value in the question seemed to just be missing the space...

Comment: It should be, but I was not sure about original AWK and I didn't know what version is used by @Basj (it is my experience from answering questions asked by another users - thyy sometimes use very strange software like busybox or ancient versions of Unix).

Comment: As far as I know, _all_ awks treat the separator as a regular expression. This even used to be marked as a bug in `man perl` (perl didn't used to support this, but does now) where they said "we should let awk be better at something". Maybe some ancient ones do not, but I really doubt it, and it's part of the [POSIX specs for awk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/awk.html). I think it's safe to assume you don't need gawk for this.

Comment: @nutilius, regardless of it being a standard feature in this case, you're not exactly wrong in general that the GNU tools _do_ have (useful) features that aren't standard and it's better to be careful before presenting them as such. Which is why I usually write "At least in GNU xyz" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want the IP address and the user agent.

The IP address is the second whitespace-delimited word. It will be in `$2` in `awk` with the default value of `FS`.

The user agent is the string in the last double quoted substring. You can get at that by deleting the last double quote, and then deleting everything up to what's now the last double quote.

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ ip = $2; sub("\"$",""); sub(".*\"",""); ua = $0; print ip; print ua }'
```

or, slightly shorter,

```
awk '{ ip = $2; sub("\"$",""); sub(".*\"",""); print ip; print }'
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -e 'h' -e 's/[^ ]* //;s/ .*//p' \
    -e 'g' -e 's/"$//;s/.*"//'
```

This first saves the line in the hold space (`h`), then extracts the IP number by deleting up to the first space and then from the (now) first space.  This isolates the IP number, which is printed.  Then the saved line is retrieved (`g`) and the same procedure as in the `awk` code is applied, i.e. delete the last double quote, and then everything up to the (now) last double quote.

Both commands print the IP number on one line, followed by the user agent string on the next.