# Parse Apache logs from command line (logs with multiple delimiters)

Tags: text-processing, awk, logs

**How to parse `/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log` and get the value of each column from command line?**

This is surely a very common problem, and [I tried with `awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638042/using-both-whitespaces-and-quotes-as-separator-for-awk), but it's not as simple as it looks, because:

- the whitespace is used a as separator
- except when we are inside quotes `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;..."`
- `[` and `]` is used for the date column

Example with the standard Apache logging as configured on Debian:

```
www.example.com:443 1.2.3.4 - - [01/Feb/2021:15:07:35 +0100] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 8317 "https://www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
```

The expected parsing should be able to extract any of these columns:

```
www.example.com:443
1.2.3.4
-
-
[01/Feb/2021:15:07:35 +0100]
"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 
200 
8317 
"https://www.example.com/" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU `awk` for the *`FPAT`* and assuming there is no inner double quotes inside double-quotes or brackets inside brackets:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|\\[[^]]*\\]|[^ ]*' '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }' infile
```

Regexes actually matches on *`char-X[not char-X]<zero-or-more-of-any-character-until>char-X`* seen.

see in the [man awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-gawk-41)

> **FPAT**
> A  regular  expression describing the contents of the
> fields in a record.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields,
> where the fields match the regular expression, instead
> of using the value of FS as the field separator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The regex you used looks mysterious for me but I'll study it :) Does this regex encode this specific log format? i.e. if a few columns were swapped in the log file, would it still work?

Comment: @Basj see the edit; and yes, it will work apart of where those column are, because it works on FPAT not on specific column position.

Answer (score 1):

First add double quotes around the date bit (1).  This gives you a valid CSV file with spaces as delimiters instead of commas.  Then use a CSV parser to read the line as a CSV record using space as the field delimiter (2).  Output the record with the delimiter set to newline (3).  Done.

1. `sed 's/\[/"&/; s/\]/&"/'`
2. `cvsformat -H -d ' '` (the `-H` is to not read a header line with column headings)
3. `csvformat -H -D $'\n'` (the `$'...'` requires a shell that understands "C strings", like `bash`, otherwise use a literal newline)

The 2nd and 3rd steps can be combined, giving you

```
sed 's/\[/"&/; s/\]/&"/' logfile | csvformat -H -d ' ' -D $'\n'
```

With the given data in `logfile`, this produces

```
www.example.com:443
1.2.3.4
-
-
[01/Feb/2021:15:07:35 +0100]
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
200
8317
https://www.example.com/
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36
```

The double quotes are removed from some of the entries as they are no longer needed.

`csvformat` is part of [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).